# (Ionic / Capacitor) --> No TypeScript source-map with build on Android device

Tags: android, typescript, ionic4, source-maps, capacitor

I am currently on a project developed width Ionic4 and Capacitor.

I want, when building my project on a smartphone (Android), get the source-map files ".ts".
For now, I only have the source-map files ".scss" and ".html".

Here are all the tests of build that I tried

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {

   "android": "npx cap copy && npx cap open android", // And sync if necessary


   "build_1: "ng build && npm run android",
   "build_2: "ng build --sourceMap && npm run android",

   "build_3: "ionic build && npm run android",
   "build_4: "ionic build --source-map && npm run android",
}
```

I also tried to add this

```
"config": {
   "ionic_generate_source_map": "true",
   "ionic_source_map_type": "inline-source-map" // Or eval-source-map
}
```

Then, finding no solution, I tried webpack.

Inside **package.json**

```
"config": {
   "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"
}
```

Inside **webpack.config.js**

```
const process = require('process');
const useDefaultConfig = require('@ionic/app-scripts/config/webpack.config.js');

const env = process.env.IONIC_ENV;

if (env === 'dev' || env === 'development') {
   useDefaultConfig[env].devtool = 'inline-source-map';
}

module.exports = () => useDefaultConfig;
```

Then, once the compilation is finished, I launch the project with Android Studio.

I inspect the sources with Chrome inspect and I only get the sources of the "html" and "scss" files, but not "TypeScript".

**Does anyone have a magic idea ?**

#### Config info

- Ionic:

  - Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.4
  - Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
  - @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
  - @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
  - @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
  - @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.4.1
- Capacitor:

  - Capacitor CLI   : 1.1.1
  - @capacitor/core : 1.1.1
- Cordova:

  - Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
  - Cordova Platforms : none
  - Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)
- Utility:

  - cordova-res : not installed
  - native-run  : 0.2.7
- System:

  - Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
  - NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
  - npm               : 6.10.3
  - OS                : Windows 10

**tsconfig.json**

```
...
"lib": ["dom", "es6"],
"module": "es6",
"target": "es6",
"sourceMap": true
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.

I use the command **npm run build_r** define in **package.json**

```
scripts: {
    "build_r": "ionic capacitor run android --source-map --livereload"
}
```

below which allows me to access the source-map